# Where can I find the HD control cap of Command Undead, Animate Dead and Control Undead?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, necromancy

I cannot find these caps on the SRD, but I know they exist, else a *Rod of Undead Mastery* and the secondary effect of a Dread Necromancer's *Undead Mastery* would be useless. Where can I find what the default HD control caps are?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are different things.

**Animated undead creatures** like skeletons and zombies that are created through the use of the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*animate dead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/animateDead.htm) [necro] (*PH* 198-9) *et al.* have the control cap (*ahem*) buried in the *animate dead* spell itself: "[Y]ou can control only 4 HD worth of undead creatures per caster level. If you exceed this number, all the newly created creatures fall under your control, and any excess undead from previous castings [of *animate dead*] become uncontrolled."

However, **created undead creatures** like the ghouls and ghasts brought forth by the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*create undead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/createUndead.htm) [necro] (*PH* 215) and the shadows and wraiths brought forth by the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*create greater undead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/createGreaterUndead.htm) [necro] (*PH* 215) are *not* automatically under the creator's control and must be managed in a different way, such as by using the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*control undead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/controlUndead.htm) [necro] (*PH* 214) or by successfully commanding them using [rebuke undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#turnOrRebukeUndead) (*PH* 159-60) or by simply forming an alliance, perhaps by employing the skills [Diplomacy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/diplomacy.htm) or [Intimidate](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/intimidate.htm).

---

The *rod of undead mastery* (*Libris Mortis* 78) (10,000 gp; 5 lbs.) affects the first kind while the *rod*'s held (and *don't let go!*). Whether the *rod* also affects undead creatures when they're controlled in ways like those needed to control the second kind of creatures is up to the DM.

Both kinds of creatures are affected in different ways by the dread necromancer's class feature undead mastery (*LM* 87), the dread necromancer both able to control more animated undead creatures and able to use the spell *control undead* to manage the more willful members of her undead horde.

Comment: Does that mean that Command Undead and Control undead initially have no HD cap?

Comment: @Joninean The spell [*control undead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/controlUndead.htm) has a Hit Dice cap (check the Target entry), but the spell [*command undead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/commandUndead.htm) is like *charm person* for undead and has no cap. The ability to command undead through [rebuke undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#turnOrRebukeUndead) is limited by effective cleric level. Makes you want to buy the developers a thesaurus, doesn't it?

Comment: While you couldn't list every undead in an answer, there are undead created by other undead (ie Vampires) who can create undead that are under their control. I believe the mentioned magic items benefit them aswell.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin I dunno. All the [vampire](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#vampire) language uses the verb *enslave* rather than *control* that's mandated by the *rod.* As a DM who reads things strictly, I'd have to have a *really* good plot in mind to rule that the *rod* doubles an NPC vampire's HD of enslaved spawn. (If I needed the vampire to enslave more spawn, and I can always just give it more HD!) Is there another non-*Monster Manual* example? (All the rest of the *MM* create spawn abilities lack a HD cap.)

Comment: Hmmm, fair point. I just remembered the phrase "under the command"..I guess I just didnt catch the "enslaved" part. Let that be a lesson, dont rely on memory kids (especially at my age!)