# How many Undead can be under a Dread Necromancer's command at any given time?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, undead, necromancy

The description of a Dread Necromancer's Undead Mastery ability says the following:

> In addition, when a dread necromancer uses the animate dead spell to create undead, she can control 4 + her Charisma bonus HD worth of undead creatures per class level (rather than the 4 HD per level normally granted by the spell).
>
> Similarly, when a dread necromancer casts the control undead spell, the spell targets up to (2 + her Cha bonus) HD/level of undead creatures, rather than the 2 HD/level normally granted by the spell.

A (Dread) Necromancer has many ways to bring Undead under their control. From Command Undead, to Create Undead, to Rebuke, and many more.
Each of these ways has a limit as to how many Undead they can command. Are all these ways of commanding undead counted seperately? I.E. can a Necromancer control an X amount of Undead through the spell Control Undead, + an X amount of Undead through rebuking them, plus an X amount of-... Etc. etc.? Or should all these methods of expanding their undead army be added together to count towards one overarching limit?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72168/8610).

Answer (score 6):

Each different method of undead management is usually computed separately. That is, a dread necromancer's pool of Hit Dice from the spell [*animate dead*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#animate-dead) is different and separate from her pool of Hit Dice for [rebuking undead](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#turn-or-rebuke-undead), and those pools don't usually interact at all with *other* management techniques like, for example, the spells [*command undead*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#command-undead) and [*control undead*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#control-undead).

It's not a matter of just putting everything in one big pile, no matter how convenient that might be. Managing a mess of minions (as [Gru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Despicable_Me) can tell you) requires intestinal fortitude, patience, and probably a spreadsheet.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning effects like *desecrate* that can also change things, as well as the tactic of leveraging undead with spawn to potentially ignore those limits entirely.

Comment: @KRyan Honestly, I think there are just too many control variables to even *begin* to address them without the answer cascading into a *What's the maximum number of undead a lone dread necromancer can control?*, so I figured a simple answer was best in this case.  However, I'll gladly upvote another answer that's more detailed.

Comment: There is no "probably". You need a spreadsheet. First hand experience with a Dread Necromancer has proven that time and again.